# How can I capture GNUMake differences between two directories

Tags: debugging, gnu-make

I have a tricky issue with gmake, when I build from the parent directory, something is different and the make does not build all the .o(s) it needs and fails, but if I cd to the directory and do a make it builds them fine.

How can I get GNUmake to tell me the difference between these two runs? There must be some make variables set in the parent that break the child, but I need help figuring out how to track them down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running `make` from the parent directory fails to build `foo.o`, then try `make foo.o`. If that fails then try running `make -n foo.o` in both directories (to *print* the commands instead of *executing* them) to see what it's doing differently. If it succeeds, then it's not even trying to build `foo.o` when run from the parent directory; `make -n` may shed some light, and as a last resort `make -d` will give you a torrent of information about the decision process, *why* it's doing what it's doing.

Here's a handy trick to see the value of variables. Put this rule in your makefile:

```
show_%:
    @echo $@ is $($*)
```

Now you can run `make show_FOO` and it will tell you the value of the variable `FOO`.

Finally, are you sure you know where you build your .o files? Make is very good at using things *there* to build files *here*, but not the other way around, so it can lose track of intermediate files if you're not careful.